# moment.js startOf working fine but endOf giving invalid value

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Hi i was just trying to get the start and end date of a month specified to do so i used the moment like below

```js
  //function to get the ranges of month specified
  function Calculate() {
  // get entered month
  const month = document.getElementById('month').value;
  console.log('You entered', month);
  
  //get today date
  //e.g. 25-08-2022
  const today = moment().clone();

  //get delta between required month and current month
  // e.g. 2
  const factor = month - (today.month() + 1);

  const startOfMonth = today.add(factor, 'M').clone().startOf('M').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  const endOfMonth = today.add(factor, 'M').clone().endOf('M').format('DD-MM-YYYY');

  console.log('Ranges', startOfMonth, endOfMonth);
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>

<label>Enter a month to get start & end dates</label><br />
<input type="number" id="month"><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="Calculate()">
```

The expected output should be like following

> Ranges 01-10-2022 31-10-2022

But i am getting the output some thing like below

> Ranges 01-10-2022 31-12-2022

the start of the month is right as expected but end of the month is not calculating right.

Comment: You should use [`clone()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/clone/) before [`add`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) since the latter _Mutates the original moment by adding time_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're cloning in the wrong place:

```
today.add(factor, 'M').clone()
```

This adds `factor` to `today`, *then* clones the result. But `today` already got changed.

Instead, clone *before* adding:

```
today.clone().add(factor, 'M')
```

Comment: Yes you are right, i updated the code corrected the clone location and now its working fine